# Can separate calls two CreateProcess() share the same startup and process info?

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

if I am using `CreateProcess()` multiple times, is okay to share the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` and `STARTUPINFO` variables? Or is it really bad practice? I've read quite a bit of documentation, but I can't find any examples about handling `CreateProcess()` calls more than once.

As an example, say I have the fake function below:

```
    int SampleClass::sampleFn1(){ 
        //Variables
        STARTUPINFOW siStartInfo; 
        PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
        memset(&siStartInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartInfo)); 
        memset(&piProcInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcInfo)); 
        siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartInfo); 

        //let us assume cmdPath = cmd.exe directory, and cmdTxtPtr has correct text
        if(!CreateProcess(cmdPath, cmdTxtPtr, NULL, NULL, false, 0, 
        NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo)){
            return 1; //failed at step 1
        }
        if(!CreateProcess(cmdPath,_T("/C ant debug"),NULL,NULL,false,0,NULL,
        (LPCTSTR)directory,&siStartInfo,&piProcInfo)){
            return 2; //failed at debug
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess,10000);
        result = GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess,&exitCode);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
        return 0;//finished
    }
```

A similar function happens to work in my program, but I'd like to make it as safe as possible.

Or... Should I do something like the code below instead:

```
    int SampleClass::sampleFn2(){   
        //Variables
        STARTUPINFOW siStartInfo; 
        PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
        memset(&siStartInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartInfo)); 
        memset(&piProcInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcInfo)); 
        siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartInfo); 

        //let us assume cmdPath = cmd.exe directory, and cmdTxtPtr has correct text
        if(!CreateProcess(cmdPath, cmdTxtPtr, NULL, NULL, false, 
        0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo)){
            return 1; //failed at update project
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess,10000);
        result = GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess,&exitCode);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);

        memset(&siStartInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartInfo)); 
        memset(&piProcInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcInfo)); 
        siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartInfo); 
        if(!CreateProcess(cmdPath,_T("/C ant debug"),NULL,NULL,
        false,0,NULL,(LPCTSTR)directory,&siStartInfo,&piProcInfo)){
            return 2; //failed at debug
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess,10000);
        result = GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess,&exitCode);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
        return 0;//finished
    }
```

Or do they both being handled poorly? Thank you.

Comment: Your first snippet is leaking the thread and process handle.  No need to wait but you *do* have to close them.

Comment: Thank you. All examples I've viewed seem to wait for the process. I pretty much followed them. Do you know why I do not need to wait in this scenario?

Comment: It is up to you to decide if you want to wait or not.  Clearly if the process runs for a week then you probably don't want to wait.  If you need the exit code then you do have to wait.  If the 2nd process requires the 1st one to finish then you do have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the `CreateProcess` function writes into both the STARTUPINFO and PROCESSINFO structure, so unless you don't care about any of that info, which I think you should, you could do the second example you give.

By doing doing memset with 0, you reset all data in the structs to 0.

I'm not sure that this is very good practice, but maybe someone else can give more insight.